# creating bucket error on AWS using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I want to create a bucket to upload some wav files in it. I am able to create a bucket manually with location required, but when I am trying to program in python to create a bucket with us-west-2 location

```
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
s3 = session.resource('s3')

s3.create_bucket(Bucket='test-asterisk1', CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-central-1'})
```

I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_bucket.py", line 10, in <module>
  s3.create_bucket(Bucket='asterisk1', CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'ap-south-1'})
  File "/home/dileep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dileep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__ response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/home/dileep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/dileep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The ap-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

I am on indian IP trying to create a 'us-west-2' end point is that creating a problem?

so I tried [changing location constrain](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2603) one by one time each

```
"LocationConstraint": "EU"|"eu-west-1"|"us-west-1"|"us-west-2"|"ap-south-1"|"ap-southeast-1"|"ap-southeast-2"|"ap-northeast-1"|"sa-east-1"|"cn-north-1"|"eu-central-1"
```

but whatever location I try it gives me the same error.

so I tried creating with boto instead of boto3

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import Location
s3 = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
s3.create_bucket('test-asterisk1', location=Location.USWest2)
```

it throws error

```
File "s2t_amazon.py", line 27, in <module>
s3.create_bucket('test-asterisk2', location=Location.USWest2)
File "/home/dileep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 623, in create_bucket
response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3CreateError: S3CreateError: 409 Conflict 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Error><Code>BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou</Code><Message>Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it. 
</Message><BucketName>test-asterisk2</BucketName> 
<RequestId>EAF26BA152FD20A5</RequestId<HostId>ep0WFZEb1mIjEgbYIY4BGGuOTi5HSutYd3XTKgFjWmRMnGG0ajj5TLF4/t1amJQsOZdZQrqGnoE=</HostId></Error>
```

I have checked if the bucket is created, and it is not created by anyone of the methods. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: Please try after adding region_name='eu-central-1' when calling boto3.Session().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'eu-central-1')

s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket='my-bucket', CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-central-1'})
```

The import thing to realise is that the command **must be sent to the region where the bucket is being created**. Thus, you'll need to specify the region when creating the client and also when creating the bucket.